# Liquibase migration fails for H2 after spring boot upgrade from 2.2 to 2.7

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, liquibase

I'm upgrading spring boot from 2.2.x to 2.7.5. One of the existing migration fails during test

`changelog.v1.mysql.sql`

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column `OLD_COLUMN` `NEW_COLUMN` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Old H2 version: `1.4.197`
New H2 version: `2.1.214`

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column `OLD_COLUMN` `NEW_COLUMN` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci [*]NOT NULL DEFAULT ''"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column `OLD_COLUMN` `NEW_COLUMN` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' [42000-214]
```

**application.properties (test)**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:system42;MODE=MySQL;NON_KEYWORDS=value
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Migration works when changed the query from

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column `OLD_COLUMN` `NEW_COLUMN` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

to

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column `OLD_COLUMN` `NEW_COLUMN` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255)` .

[H2 reference guide](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type)

Comment: is there a way to fix without modifying migration?

Comment: can't you use it like this ? `ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column OLD_COLUMN NEW_COLUMN VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''; `